# Websphere 7 log not working from RAD ide but works when WAS start as Windows Service

Tags: logging, windows-service, websphere

i have the following strange behavior in WAS 7:

1. When WAS Start as Windows Service, the log are write OK in the profile/log folder.
2. When WAS is started from Rational IDE, the log don't work (the only files that are writed are Activity.log and the profile/log/server_name/System*.log

I check that WAS is started with the SYSTEM user as Service (from eclipse was start as the logged user) , so using psexec i run eclipse (rad) as SYSTEM user but the log are not writed (so is not an user/permissions problem).

The difference between startServer.log are:

log was start as Service:

```
00000000 WsServerContr 1   Executing executeUtilityOnWindows with args: was_path\profiles\AppSrv01\config cell_name node_name server_name -fromWinService \\.\pipe\<some_id>
00000000 WsServerContr 1   invokedByWindowsService has been set to true earlier
```

log was start from RAD:

```
00000000 WsServerContr 1   Executing executeUtilityOnWindows with args: was_path\profiles\AppSrv01\config cell_name node_name server_name -script ws_path\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\quickServerStart.bat
```

Well, thanks for reading and your answers, i hope that we can search for a solution to this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If enabled, RAD/Eclipse uses a quick server startup mechanism for the embedded WebSphere Test Environment (WTE) in which it runs a batch file located in the workspace called quickServerStart.bat for Windows platform.  When this option is turned on for a server config (and it is on by default), the native_std*.log and startServer.log files are not generated but the System*.log files are.  If you need to see the other log files, you can disable this behavior by opening the Server Editor (double-click on the server name in Servers view) and uncheck "Start server with a generated script" under the "Optimize server start for development" section of the editor.

Comment: Thanks. This is interesting, i'll checkout monday :), i want to know whats the difference between eclipse/rad start and the "service" start, this help a lot :) thanks again ;)